# How do I combine trim and replace functions to remove spaces anywhere in the string?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this function (TRIM_REPLACE) that gets spaces from both the right and the left of a string. However, I am trying to modify it so that it trims in the middle also but I would rather combine the function than to do it separately.

*Example*: Let's say I have a name

```
Input
--------------------------
Peter<space><space>Griffin
```

`<space>` indicate one blank space in the above input.

I would like to trim the additional space in the so that it looks like this:

```
Output
--------------------------
Peter<space>Griffin
```

As you can see that the multiple spaces are replaced with a single space.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TRIM_REPLACE
(
    @STRING     VARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
    BEGIN
        RETURN LTRIM(RTRIM(@STRING))  + REPLACE(@STRING, '  ',' ')  
    END
GO
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Might be time to go with CLR to gain acces to Regex.   That way it is a single call.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are only concerned about pairs of spaces, you can use . . .

```
ltrim(rtrim(replace(@String, '  ', ' ')))
```

If you might have multiple spaces, you need to put this into a loop:

```
while charindex('  ', @string) > 0
begin
    set @string = replace(@string, '  ', ' ');
end;
return ltrim(rtrim(@string));
```

Comment: Good answer, but I don't think you need to loop based on this documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx.  Looks like it does a global replace by default.

Comment: Hello, I tested the above example, it seem the LOOP is need to move multiple spaces, Example: I added a work to the column: Peter------Griggin and without the Loop, it returns: Peter----Griggin, only one space is removed. Using the Loop returns: Peter-Griffin.

Comment: @Unaverage, Your comment is clear enough but I believe you meant "Griffin" in all cases (as opposed to "Griggin" in the first two and "Griffin" in the last)